# How to sort habits by priority in the org-agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit

How can I sort habits in the org-agenda first by priority, then schedule + deadline + consistency?

I tried to set the `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` to various configurations, but ultimately habits are always sorted first by schedule + deadline + consistency followed by priority, the opposite of what I want.

I strongly prefer to avoid modifying the org source code like [this SO question does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200762/sort-todays-habits-by-priority-in-main-agenda-view).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [some guidance by Nicolas Goaziou](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-04/msg00320.html), I  created a solution that sorts the way I want by taking advantage of the `user-defined` sorting strategy:

```
(defun hw-org-agenda-sort-habits (a b)
  "Sort habits first by user priority, then by schedule+deadline+consistency."
  (let ((ha (get-text-property 1 'org-habit-p a))
        (hb (get-text-property 1 'org-habit-p b)))
    (when (and ha hb)
      (let ((pa (org-get-priority a))
            (pb (org-get-priority b)))
        (cond ((> pa pb) +1)
              ((< pa pb) -1)
              ((= pa pb) (org-cmp-values a b 'priority)))))))
(setq org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'hw-org-agenda-sort-habits
      org-agenda-sorting-strategy '((agenda time-up user-defined-down habit-down)
                                    (todo priority-down category-keep)
                                    (tags priority-down category-keep)
                                    (search category-keep)))
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it does the job.

Comment: @holoncronweaver, might be nice to add the link to the org mailing list discussion with Nicolas you reference above. I'd like to check it out.

Comment: @Joe Done. His advice was simply to use `org-agenda-cmp-user-defined`, not much discussion beyond that I'm afraid.